# Use JAVA to Place data into buckets of data based on range of values

Tags: java

I need to create buckets of data based on information being read from rows of data in a database.  As long as there is no gap in the data range they belong in the same bucket otherwise create a new bucket and if a range overlaps two buckets then combine and extend.

I then need to add the final buckets to a list but am not sure how to do this.

I have the following basic code to show how the buckets are calculated:

```
double start,startx,stop,stopx;

start = 0;
stop = 0;

//Row 1 of Data
startx = 1;
stopx = 2;

if (startx > stopx) {
    stop = stopx;
}

if (stopx > stop){
    stop = stopx;
}

if (startx < start){
    start = startx;
}



System.out.println("Start = " + start\n + "Stop = " + stop\n\n)
```

> After 1 Row the Bucket is:    Start = 1.0 Stop = 3.0

```
//Row 2 of Data
start = 2;
stop = 5


if (startx > stopx) {
    stop = stopx;
}

if (stopx > stop){
    stop = stopx;
}

if (startx < start){
    start = startx;
}

System.out.println("Start = " + start\n + "Stop = " + stop )
```

> After the second row of data the bucket is now:
>   Start = 1.0
>   Stop = 5.0

```
//Row 3 of Data
start = 7;
stop = 9;


if (startx > stopx) {
    stop = stopx;
}

if (stopx > stop){
    stop = stopx;
}

if (startx < start){
    start = startx;
}

System.out.println("Start = " + start + "\nStop = " + stop + "\n\n");
```

> Since row 3's starting range is outside the existing bucket range I
>   need to create a new bucket so I would have two buckets now. Bucket 1
>   :  Start = 1 Stop = 5  Bucket 2: Start = 7 Stop = 9

```
//Row 4 of Data
start = 5;
stop = 10;


if (startx > stopx) {
    stop = stopx;
}

if (stopx > stop){
    stop = stopx;
}

if (startx < start){
    start = startx;
}

System.out.println("Start = " + start + "\nStop = " + stop + "\n\n");
```

> Since the data in row 4 goes over bucket 1 and 2 they need to be
>   combined so I have a result of Bucket 1: Start = 1 Stop = 10

I need to be able to combine and recreate buckets based on the data of each row so that they are consolidated as appropriate.

Comment: how can stopx be greater than itself?

Comment: You are right @GregorioMerazJr. i fixed that typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you're going to want to do is sort your ranges by their start points. So if you have the ranges 1-2, 2-5, 7-9, and 5-10, arrange them in a List and sort by their start number so they're in the order 1-2, 2-5, 5-10, and 7-9.

Then iterate over this list. Starting with the first element create a new bucket having start 1 and end 2. As you see each element in the list, check if it belongs in the previous bucket. If it does, merge them. If it doesn't make a new bucket. Because your elements are ordered by their start number, if one element doesn't belong in the previous bucket none of the following elements will belong in it either.

Therefore, when you create a new bucket, you are sure that all the previous buckets are complete.

This allows you to go over the elements only once, although it requires a sort, so it will have nlog(n) complexity.